# Best practice to sketch difficult functions.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

what's the best practice to sketch a difficult function such as:
$$
y=x^3+3cos(x)+x
$$
or
$$
y=e^{x}-\frac{4}{9}e^{3x}+\frac{1}{3}x+\frac{4}{9}
$$
when i'm on a test, how can i sketch them in a small time? I mean, without giving a complete function analysis because it would takes too long.

This question is extended also when you have to sketch level curves of a function in 2 variables such as:

given $$f(x,y)=2/10$$
$$
\frac{2}{10}=x^{\frac{4}{5}}sin(\frac{4}{5}y)
$$

What's the best practice to overcome this situation?